# Exception doesn't get catched using rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My route file :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    resources :line_items

    resources :carts, param: :number

end
```

my Cart Model :

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord

    def to_param 
        number
    end

    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

end
```

my LineItem Model

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]

    def create
       # stuff here ....
    end

    private

        def set_cart

            @cart = Cart.find(55)

        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

            # @cart = Cart.create!

            session[:cart_number] = @cart.number

        end

end
```

I am doing this in my `before_action :set_cart`

```
def set_cart

    @cart = Cart.find_by!(number: session[:cart_number]) 

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

    @cart = Cart.create

    session[:cart_number] = @cart.number

end
```

When I run the code I got the error of the exception `Couldn't find Cart` and the rescue part isn't catching the error, I tried using general exception `rescue Exception` but this doesn't work either

**Update**

I found that that the error was from my Cart model, where I have this :

```
before_create :generate_cart_number

MAX_RETRIES = 5

def generate_cart_number
   update_column :number, SecureRandom.hex(16/4).upcase
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
   @token_attempts = @token_attempts.to_i + 1
   retry if @token_attempts < MAX_RETRIES
   raise e, "Retries exhausted"
end
```

When I commented out that method, the rescue in the `set_cart` method start to work, I don't know what's exactly the issue here but it's working! thanks to everyone tried to help

Comment: Try moving `@cart = Cart.create` and `session[:cart_number] = @cart.number` out of `begin` and `rescue`

Comment: @Pavan it doesn't work, I also get rid of begin block (see updated code) and I get the error `Couldn't find Cart`

Comment: !Is the issue that `Cart.create` fails, due to some validation error? For example, if you have a required parameter/association/etc that must be set in the cart upon creation? Try changing that to `Cart.create!`, and see if it raises an exception.

Comment: Moreover, your question doesn't completely make sense -- that error message cannot be occurring with this code. Can you provide the full stack trace, double check that you've actually saved the file, and show any more code context if necessary?

Comment: @TomLord I commented out the `Cart.create` part and even used  `Cart.find(55)` a random id 55 to test with but I stil get the same error, see I added some code spinets

Comment: I'm still not convinced the information you've provided in the question is an accurate representation of your code/error... A couple of things you could try: (1) Wrap that line in an explicit **`begin`** ... `rescue` ... **`end`**. (2) Try writing something else, like `raise "TEST!"` to double-check that this really is where the error is coming from.

Comment: @TomLord I don't believe that my self, I tried also by moving the code to another controller and yes I double checked that this is where the error comes from!! that's weird I have no idea why ! yesterday I generated an action cable command : `rails​​ ​​generate​​ ​​channel​​ ​​products` I am not sure if this can cause some issue !

Comment: Can you show the **full** error message in your post? Like I say, I still don't believe the information is accurate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146371/discussion-between-medbo-and-tom-lord).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have a method to set a cart's number, so I'm gonna recommend using the ID instead.

```
def set_cart
  @cart = Cart.find_by(id: session[:cart_id])
  if @cart
     #Do what you want to do if it exists
  else
     @cart = Cart.create
     session[:cart_id]= @cart.id
  end
end
```

Comment: ...Except that this is doing something different. OP had written `session[:cart_number] = @cart.number`, **not** `@cart.number = session[:cart_number]`. (Although perhaps that's what they actually intended to write??)

Comment: You're right, I thought this is what OP was trying to do. Can OP please clarify?

Comment: @medBo What do you want to do when the find fails, i.e. the cart doesn't exist yet? Create a new cart using session[:cart_number]? Because if so, the solution I suggested will work.
Also find(55) fails because you're trying to find it with the id (the autoincrementing one) instead of the number. You might want find_by(number: 55)

Comment: @HansCristobal now I needed to catch the exception because if it doesn't work here it won't work somewhere else and that break the functionality of the app itself :(

Comment: @medBo What are you going to do after catching the exception? It's always better to not have to use rescue. As I've said, if you're going to create a new cart after finding out that one doesn't exist yet, you can use my solution.

Comment: @medBo updated my answer as I think I understand what you're trying to do now

Comment: @HansCristobal yes this is what I wanted to do, but I was annoyed because the rescue wasn't working, I found the issue, read my updated post at the end, let me know if you understand the issue :)